# How to make interactive Google Charts in Angular (UI-event)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

I wonder if there is a good way to handle google charts API events in Angular?

(Dont have enough reputation to make proper links out of these references:)

I'm using 
[bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/]

and trying to port 
[github.com/angular-ui/ui-map/blob/master/ui-map.js]

's way of handling events with 
[github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/blob/master/modules/event/event.js].

---

Here is a plunker showing non-interactive chart:

http://plnkr.co/edit/RTx8UgZdEvDmYoPUu4Xf

What I would like to happen is that the foo()-method (showing an alert) would get called when a selection is made in the chart.

---

#### Template:

`<div data-google-chart chart="chart" class="chart" ui-event="{'chart-select':'foo()'}">`

#### Directive:

```
angular.module('googlechart.directives', ['ui.event']).directive('googleChart',     ['$timeout', '$window', function ($timeout, $window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            chart: '=chart'
        },
        link: function ($scope, $elm, $attr) {
            var eventNames="select ready onmouseover animationfinish error onmouseout";          

         /* ... Set up the chart and chartwrapper. */

            google.visualization.events.addListener($scope.chartWrapper, 'ready', function () {
                bindChartEvents($scope, eventNames, $scope.chartWrapper.getChart(), $elm);
            });

        }
    };
    function bindChartEvents(scope, eventsStr, chart, element) {
      angular.forEach(eventsStr.split(' '), function (eventName) {
          google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, eventName, function (event) {
              var newEventName = 'chart-' + eventName;
              element.triggerHandler(newEventName, event);
              if (!scope.$$phase){
                  scope.$apply();
              }
          });
      });
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dropped the ui-event part and injected eventlisteners directly to the chart-object that I'm passing into the directive.

```
function bindChartEvents(scope) {
   if(typeof $scope.chart.methods !== "undefined" && typeof $scope.chart.methods.select  !== "undefined"){
        $scope.selectListener = google.visualization.events.addListener($scope.chartWrapper, "select", function (event) {
            $scope.chart.methods.select($scope.chartWrapper.getChart().getSelection(), event);
        });
    }
  });
```